# MVC Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have problem with my first MVC project. I'm trying to change values of DropDownList of surnames when select DropDownList of doctor types. I think my action is working. But I cannot use result in view.
Here my codes:

```js
$(function () {
            $('select#mCB').change(function () {
                var docId = $(this).val();

                $.ajax({
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: 'spec=' + docId,
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'LoadDoctors',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (key, Docs) {
                            $('select#shCB').append('<option value="0">Select One</option>');

                            $.each(Docs, function (index, docc) {
                                $('select#shCB').append(
                                    '<option value="' + docc.Id + '">' + docc.Name + '</option>');
                            });
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (docID) {

                        alert(' Error !');
            }
                });
            });
        });
```

Actions:

```
public static List<Docs> GetDoctorBySpec(string spec)
        {
            List<Docs> list = new List<Docs>();

            string query = "select ID, Familiyasi, Speciality from Doktorlar where Speciality=@spec";
            SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(DataBase.ConnectionString);
            Connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Connection);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@spec", spec);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                list.Add(new Docs
                { 
                    Id = dr.GetString(0),
                    Name = dr.GetString(1)

                });
            }

            return list;
        }
enter code here
enter code here
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult LoadDoctors(string spec)
    {
        List<Docs> list = DoctorsService.GetDoctorBySpec(spec);

        if (list == null)
        {
            return Json(null);
        }

        return Json(list);

    }
```

And here my DropDownLists:

```html
<div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DoktorTuri)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DoktorTuri, new SelectList(ViewBag.Vrachlar), new { @id = "mCB", @class = "vrachlar" })
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Shifokori)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Shifokori, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { @id = "shCB", @class = "vrachlar" })
            </div>
```

Where is my mistake? Thanks for answers

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Have you tried to run fiddler to see what is actually being called and that it is actually hitting your action method or even tried to run it in debug mode and break point within your action method to see if it is actually being hit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `500 (Internal Server Error)` almost always means that your throwing an exception on the server. Best guess is in your case it's because your method

```
DoctorsService.GetDoctorBySpec(spec);
```

does not accept `null` as a parameter and the value of `spec` is `null` because your never pass it value to the controller. As stann1 has noted your ajax option needs to be

```
data: {spec: docId},
```

In addition, you do not specify the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` parameter which means the method will fail.

All of this can be easily determined by debugging your code, both on the server and by using your browser tools (in particular the `Network` tab to see what is being sent and received along with error messages)

However this is only one of many problems with your code.

Firstly, unless `Docs` contains only 2 properties (the values you need for the option's `value` attribute and display text), your unnecessarily wasting bandwidth and degrading performance by sending a whole lot of data to the client which is never used. Instead, send a collection of anonymous objects

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult LoadDoctors(string spec)
{
  List<Docs> list = DoctorsService.GetDoctorBySpec(spec);
  if (list == null)
  {
    return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
  var data = list.Select(d => new
  {
    Value = d.Id,
    Text = d.Name
  });
  return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Next, your script will only ever generate multiple `<option value="0">Select One</option>` elements (one for each item in the collection) because `data` in `$.each(data, function (key, Docs) {` is your collection, and `Docs` is the item in the collection. Your second `$.each()` function will never produce anything because `Docs` is not a collection.

You script should be (note I have use the short version `$.getJSON()` rather than the longer `$.ajax()` and also used the default `id` attributes generated by the html helpers - its not clear why you would want to change the id's using `new { id = "mCB" }`?)

```
var url = '@Url.Action("LoadDoctors")'; // never hard code your url's
var shifokori = $('#Shifokori'); // cache it
$('#DoktorTuri').change(function () {
  $.getJSON(url, { spec: $(this).val() }, function(data) {
    if (!data) { // only necessary depending on the version of jquery
      // oops
    }
    // clear existing options and append empty option with NULL value (not zero) 
    // so validation will work
    shifokori.empty().append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Select One'));
    $.each(data, function (index, doc) {
      shifokori.append($('<option></option>').val(doc.Value).text(doc.Text));
    });
  }).fail(function (result) {
    // oops
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I have problem in code below:     var data = list.Select(d => new[]
              {
                
                Value = d.Id,
                Text = d.Name
              });

Comment: Here 'No best type found for implicitly-typed array' error on 'new' keyword and 'The name Value & Text does not exists in the current context' errors in parentheses

Comment: Anyway it not working :( there no errors. But no result in second DropDownList.

Comment: oooooo it works!!!!! Thank you very much. The last problem was with my #id. I corrected it. Now Working. Thank you :)

Comment: Pleasure. Note if your jquery version is 1.9+, then you don't really need the `if (!data)` block (returning `Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` will go straight to the `fail()` callback

Answer (score 1):

The **data** param of the call needs to be a Javascript object literal:

```
 $.ajax({
         dataType: 'json',
         data: {spec: docId},
         method: 'GET',
         ....
        });
```

Also, try to debug your controller and use a rest extension (or Fiddler) to test the payload, you would catch such error easily yourself ;)